# Transpose unique data from column into 1 row in new sheet with more than 1 separator columns with headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

While searching for a function to use, I found the below formula to adapt from.

```
=TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(A1:A30&"|"&rept("|",1),,2^99),"|",1,0))))
```

What has worked so far is the use of the below formula but

- **I can't seem to change it to more than 1 separator column.**

  ={(ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"|"&rept("|",1),,3^99),"|",1,0))))}

Also, is it possible to **add headers to the currently empty separator columns** in the sequence of example: `"qty","expiry","available qty"` before the next column and repeat again "qty","expiry","available qty"

Test spreadsheet in at cell I1 (Join function doesn't work as there's a limit):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w64R9QR_pAvdGy7IZLsHFvhIYIGL7lqsl_vFXrqsQMc/edit#gid=799170483

Comment: Do you have an example that shows what you need and what you have? But generally, try to read through the formulas and understand what you are doing in each step. This is possible but difficult to know what to say without seeing the data and desired outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w64R9QR_pAvdGy7IZLsHFvhIYIGL7lqsl_vFXrqsQMc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking at your sheet, seems you have already solved the issue. If not please explain further by editing your question.

Comment: @marikamitsos I have bolded the parts I need to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following formula and adjust ranges to your needs:

```
={(ArrayFormula(TRIM(SPLIT(QUERY(UNIQUE(A2:A)&"|qty|expiry|available qty"&rept("|",1),,2^99),"|",1,0))))}
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`TRIM`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)